# $X$ and $Y$ are random independent variables such that ...

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are random independent variables such that:
$$P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$$ $$P(Y=1)=P(Y=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$$
We have that $Z=X\cdot Y$. Are $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ independent?

**MY SOLUTION:**

$X, Y, Z$ are independent if $P(X\cap Y\cap Z) = P(X)P(Y)P(Z)$.
$$Z = \left \{ (1)(1), (1)(-1), (-1)(1), (-1)(-1) \right \} = \left \{ -1,1 \right \}.$$ So, $$X = \left \{ -1,1 \right \}. P(X) = \frac{1}{2}.$$ $$Y=\left \{ -1,1 \right \}.P(Y) = \frac{1}{2}.$$ $$Z=\left \{ -1,1 \right \}.P(Z) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
$$X\cap Y\cap Z = \left \{ -1,1 \right \}.$$ $$P(X\cap Y\cap Z) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
So, since $P(X\cap Y\cap Z) = \frac{1}{2} \neq  \frac{1}{8} = P(X)P(Y)P(Z)$, $X,Y,Z$ are NOT independent.

Is this correct?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

These three random variables are **pairwise** independent, i.e. any two of them are independent, and hence they are uncorrelated (i.e. the covariance, and hence the correlation, between any two of them is $0$) **but they are not independent.** The fact that knowing $X$ and $Y$ completely determines $Z$ means they cannot be independent, and the argument given in the question also proves that.

Thus

- $X,Y$ are independent,
- $X,Z$ are independent,
- $Y,Z$ are independent,
- $X,Y,Z$ are *not* independent.

These three random variables are also exchangeable, i.e. their probability distribution is invariant under permutations of this set of three random variables.